# Is This Still Chain Homotopy?

Tags: terminology, homological-algebra

Two maps between chain complexes are homotopic if there is a function $P$ such that
$$
f-g=\partial P+P\partial.
$$
What if we instead had
$$
f-g=\partial P?
$$
Then $f$ and $g$ still induce the same map on homology, as they differ by a boundary.  Would we still say that $f$ and $g$ are chain homotopic?

Comment: I don't see any reason to say that $f$ and $g$ are chain homotopic if we cannot verify the definition of them being chain homotopic. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @Rasmus I am reading a book, and they claim that two maps are chain homotopic.  But, the chain homotopy they give is of the type in my post.  I was just wondering if it is standard to use "chain homotopy" in this context.

Comment: Maybe in your special case they are equivalent, such as for 2-term complexes. Care to give a reference?